# Error while showing JSON index on single result page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

This is JSON response.

```
{
    "listing": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Institute Name",
        "contact": "9876543210",
        "website": "http://www.domain.in",
        "email": "hello@domain.in",
        "about": "Technical institute",
        "products": "PHP, Web, Mobile",
        "category_id": "3",
        "user_id": "31",
        "address": "201,Mumbai, Maharashtra 400051",
        "created_at": "2018-02-01 17:18:44",
        "updated_at": "2018-04-11 16:28:00",
        "listingIcon": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dptwdk7ky/image/upload/v1522756229/test-tube_cfqfmm.png",
        "icon": null
    }
}
```

my HTML code

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-header>
    {{listing.about}}
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    The British use the term "header", but the American term "head-shot" the English simply refuse to adopt.
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Code for calling api

```
 getListingDetail(id){

    this.authService.postData("id="+id,"list/view").then((result) => {

    this.resposeData = result;
    //console.log(this.resposeData);
    this.listing = this.resposeData.listing;


        //this.listings = this.resposeData.data.list.data;

        console.log(this.listing);
        // localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.resposeData) )
        // this.navCtrl.push(Login);


})
 }
```

[image]

Getting above error.. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: can you try to display `listing` using `{{listing | json}}` to check the value of listing in template

Comment: getting same JSON in a template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing will initially be undefined, because of the nature of async HTTP calls.

Change your template to the following:

```
{{listing?.about}}
```

This is known as the safe navigation operator, and won't fall over if listing is null / undefined. You can read more about it here: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths